# Defining a local search solver as generic as possible

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working on a hobby project, where I try to paint a copy of the Mona Lisa using local search. How it works: I start off with an empty canvas, I generate changes in the solution (neighbors) by generating shapes and colors. The solver should then check if the change improves the solution or not, and apply accordingly. However, I want to be able to use the solver in multiple ways. For instance, I want an implementation that solves the shape painting problem, and I also want a version that draws on the canvas using a colored planar subdivision, as well as a solver that creates a color palette to improve the color generator.

For this, I need to write the local search solver as generic as possible. I've tried to do this by creating interfaces for the solver, solution, solution change and solution checker, but it's starting to become a mess with the pairing of the implementations of these interfaces. I'd imagine that I would have to specify for which solution a change has to be (e.g., a shape painter change can't be applied to a color palette solution), but I'm not sure what the best approach for this would be.

This is my code so far. It's incorrect and full of errors, but it gives a general idea of what I want:

```
public interface ISolver<TSolution, TChange, TSolutionChecker>
    where TSolution : ISolution<TSolutionChecker, TChange>
    where TChange : IChange<TSolution>
    where TSolutionChecker : ISolutionChecker<TChange>
{
    TSolution Solve(TSolutionChecker checker, TSolution initialSolution);
}

// I got recursive parameter definitions here, but I don't know how to fix this
public interface ISolution<TSolutionChecker, TChange>
    where TSolutionChecker : ISolutionChecker</* error */TSolution, TChange>
    where TChange : IChange</* error */TSolution>
{
    TChange GenerateChange();
    void ApplyChange(TChange change);
    ISolution<TSolutionChecker, TChange> Clone();
}

// Again, recursive typing
public interface ISolutionChecker<TSolution, TChange>
    where TSolution : ISolution</* error */TSolutionChecker, TChange>
    where TChange : IChange<TSolution>
{
    bool IsFeasible(TSolution solution);
    long ScoreDiff(TSolution solution, TChange change);
}

public interface IChange<TSolution>
{
    void Apply(TSolution solution);
}
```

Is this the best way to do this, or is there a more elegant (and correct) solution to my problem? ChatGPT was talking about using `in` and `out` in the type parameters to specify covariance and contravariance, but I'm completely new to that topic, so all help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove these recursive typing errors (reason in comments):

```cs
public interface ISolver<TSolution, TChange, TSolutionChecker>
    where TSolution : ISolution<TChange>
    where TChange : IChange<TSolution>
    where TSolutionChecker : ISolutionChecker<TSolution, TChange>
{
    TSolution Solve(TSolutionChecker checker, TSolution initialSolution);
}

// Removed TSolutionChecker, as I understand, we don't need it here
// For the TChange, we will just implement IChange<TSolution>
public interface ISolution<TChange>
{
    TChange GenerateChange();
    void ApplyChange(TChange change);
    ISolution<TChange> Clone();
}

// TSolution is the correct type parameter for ISolution<TChange>, not TSolutionChecker
public interface ISolutionChecker<TSolution, TChange>
    where TSolution : ISolution<TChange>
    where TChange : IChange<TSolution>
{
    bool IsFeasible(TSolution solution);
    long ScoreDiff(TSolution solution, TChange change);
}

public interface IChange<TSolution>
{
    void Apply(TSolution solution);
}
```